# ListView not scaling correctly

Tags: android, listview

my ListView I would like to be about a height of 50dp, but the problem is no matter what value I set the xml layout file too, it automatically makes it much bigger. 
Here is my listview layout:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainListView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />
```

My rowview is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/usernameTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my LocalQueueAdapter

```
package .skyrealm.com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by RockyFish on 1/24/16.
*/
public class LocalQueueAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> localQueueInfo;

        public LocalQueueAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> localQueueInfo)
        {
            this.context = context;
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.localQueueInfo = localQueueInfo;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return localQueueInfo.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return localQueueInfo.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder
        {
            TextView songNameTextView, artistNameTextView, usernameTextView, numberEditText;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.local_queue_list_item, null);
            Holder holder = new Holder();
            holder.songNameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.songNameTextView);
            holder.artistNameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.artistNameTextView);
            holder.usernameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTextView);
            holder.numberEditText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);


            holder.songNameTextView.setText("  " + localQueueInfo.get(position).get(1));
            holder.artistNameTextView.setText(" - " + localQueueInfo.get(position).get(2));
            holder.usernameTextView.setText(localQueueInfo.get(position).get(4));
            holder.numberEditText.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1) + ".");

            if(position == 0)
            {
                rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#45B8AC"));
            } else if(position == 1)
            {
                rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#74E2D5"));
            }
            return rowView;
        }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: try `android:layout_height="50dp"` in your `RelativeLayout `

Comment: You mean you want your items to be 50dp??

Comment: Correct.
@Mohit I tried that and it didn't change my layout

Comment: Why do you think that something should be around 50dp. Your are not defining anything to be as such.

Comment: Regardless of what it should look like, I can change it to 200dp and it still will not change

Comment: Could you attach the adapter?

Comment: Sure I will attach it right now, thanks for the help. @DavidRauca

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inflater. I'm not really sure why. The code below should work for you. Also, you didn't understand how to use ViewHolder (Here is an example and the explanation: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.local_queue_list_item, parent, false);
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        holder.songNameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.songNameTextView);
        holder.artistNameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.artistNameTextView);
        holder.usernameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTextView);
        holder.numberEditText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    Holder holder = convertView.getTag();

    ....

    return convertView;
}
```